# For loop a dictionary in JS - how to achieve the goal?

Tags: javascript, image, loops

I need to display an Image Gallery from my server pics . I can only accomodate just 16 images per page . My JS loops over the dictionary and displays it over a 4X4 using a table created dynamically . When the loop is over 16 I do a innerhtml='' and flush the contents in the page . 
How do I iterate over 100 such images and display all the images - page by page ? Is there a more intelligent way to achieve it ? Maybe you could do something like put a < > buttons and do this .

Btw I get the full list of image from the server before processing them . I can ofcourse call the same page from server by senting just 16 images at a time .

```js
image_dict = {img1: url, img2: url2..............img1000: url1000}
```

Now I iterate over this loop like this is a non stop loop . I need to restrict it till 16 and display some options to go to next and previous - some kind of splicing comes to my mind .

```js
for (var key in image_dict) 
{  
    add_image(image_dict[key],key)
}
```

Comment: You are looking for a 'paging' solution. The solution may depend on your use of server-side framework (PHP, ASP.NET). Are you using any of that to create the page?

Comment: Yes I am looking for a paging solution , I am wondering if I should think about it server side or from front end . If its Server Side - does that mean I have opt for AJAX ?

Comment: there's no point in paging on the client, once all of the data has been downloaded, why bother.

Comment: You won't be able to do this reliably with an object because the enumeration order of object properties is undefined and varies between browsers. If you need order, you need an array.